# Create new Uri using Url encoded string in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, uri, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

**Question:**

I need to create Uri which Contains all its attributes like (OriginalString, Query) as URL encoded.

**What I tried:**

I am able to format input string of Uri with below options:

```
string encodedString = inputString.Replace("'", "%27"); //example encoding
```

OR

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode (inputString)
```

Tried all approaches to convert string to encoded string, like EscapeDataString/EscapeUriString etc

**What I need to achieve**

```
var uri = new Uri(encodedString);
```

When I create new Uri (like above) again `%27` is replaced by `'`.

**UPDATE 1:**
Not all fields of uri are converted into %27. OriginalString is converted in my case.

I want to pass this uri to HttpClient.

Do we have any mechanism to make Uri with encoded string.

Comment: When I use `string encodedString = @"https://www.google.com/q?=How'To'Cook'Apples"; encodedString = encodedString.Replace("'", "%27"); Uri x = new Uri(encodedString); 
Console.WriteLine(x.AbsoluteUri); // outputs https://www.google.com/q?=How%27To%27Cook%27Apples` It seems to work fine, Unless I misunderstand the question

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input?

Comment: Yeah, above sample provided by @DekuDesu can be used.
It is in Xamarin .NET standard project. Seems to be working in plain .NET project.
I will check and update question if required. Thanks guys for replies.

Comment: See my update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on locale settings and used keyboard, iOS may use some other apostrophe-like character, for example right single quotation mark U+2019 (').
Solution was to handle that.

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try with HttpUtility.UrlEncode(input string).
Refer to https://secretgeek.net/uri_enconding for more details.

Comment: Please consider adding the answer along with the source :)